# Drupal, nginx, ssl, and php - a nightmare

Tags: php, drupal, ssl, nginx

I think I'll cross post to stackoverflow as well;  Here's my issue:
I have installed an ssl certificate on my server, and read a whole lot and did all the different suggested things, but I cannot seem to get the $_SERVER['HTTPS'] variable to show up.  Someone please help.  Here's my config:

Server: 
Linode 
Ubuntu 8.02LTS
nginx - latest
created a vhost:

```
server {
            listen   443;
            server_name  www.buzzonstage.com;
            rewrite ^/(.*) https://buzzonstage.com/$1 permanent;
       }

server {
            listen   443;
            server_name buzzonstage.com;
            ssl on;
            ssl_certificate /usr/local/nginx/conf/buzzonstage.com.pem;
            ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/nginx/conf/buzzonstage.com.key;
            access_log /home/maksimize/public_html/buzzonstage.com/log/access.log;
            error_log /home/maksimize/public_html/buzzonstage.com/log/error.log;
            location /  {
                        root   /home/maksimize/public_html/buzzonstage.com/public/;
                        index  index.php index.html;
                        if (!-e $request_filename)
                        {
                        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
                        }
                        }
            # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
            location ~ \.php$
                    {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include /usr/local/nginx/conf/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/maksimize/public_html/buzzonstage.com/public/$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
            }
       }

server {
            listen   80;
            server_name  www.buzzonstage.com;
            rewrite ^/(.*) http://buzzonstage.com/$1 permanent;
       }
server {
            listen   80;
            server_name buzzonstage.com;
            access_log /home/maksimize/public_html/buzzonstage.com/log/access.log;
            error_log /home/maksimize/public_html/buzzonstage.com/log/error.log;
            location /  {
                        root   /home/maksimize/public_html/buzzonstage.com/public/;
                        index  index.php index.html;
                        if (!-e $request_filename)
                        {
                        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
                        }
                        }
            # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
            location ~ \.php$
                    {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include /usr/local/nginx/conf/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/maksimize/public_html/buzzonstage.com/public/$fastcgi_script_name;
```

The verification from digicert comes back accurate, but I get a message saying that some info may not be secure - I understand this is the case because of the various links to non-secure pages on the site.  The phpinfo shows up green https;

But in order for a certain drupal module to work - securepages - I need to be able to show a that variable in the $_SERVER array.  Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That Twitter module is breaking SSL. Modify it so it will pass only through SSL (requires rewriting the widget so it loads locally, yes it's possible), and everything should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
The phpinfo shows up green https;
```

This is good. Because phpinfo works with $_SERVER['HTTPS'] variable. And it's certainly defined.

```
but I get a message saying that some info may not be secure
```

```
But in order for a certain drupal module to work - securepages
I need to be able to show a that variable in the $_SERVER array.
```

Hmm, may be this modules trying to work without https? For example through  AJAX?
And where they getting answer, HTTPS is not defined.
Try to check this, by adding `fastcgi_param HTTPS on;` to NON https section of your config. I think all will start working. But obvious, it's a cheat...

Comment: I do use ajax to load stuff in on the site.  Sorry I forgot to mention that the site is locked down right now.  I did the cheat, and still no luck.  I really only need it to show up on a few pages - namely the checkout and the checkout review page. The rest of the site doesn't need https at all.  Any other things you think may work?